# javafx : Draggable node inside scrollpane scrollbar not drag bind drag with node

Tags: javafx

I have draggable node which placed in scroll pane with vertical scrollbar but scrollbar drag not working . i think because drag event bind with node so how make these two drag events independently . like node is scene which not having property like setpickbounds(). so is there any solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I am writing code on scene and when event trigger it call method
>   event.consume();
>   which filter other listener on it.
>   i just remove consume event to allow other component to work with it 
>   That It !